# Visit visa for UK rejected in 2018 for insufficient funds. Will that affect work permit permit visa when I apply in 2023?

Tags: working-visas, uk-visa, indian-citizens

I applied for visit visa in 2018 and got rejected not sure why. Now I am trying to apply for workpermit visa and want to check if that rejected visa will affects my application for workpermit.

It's been 5 years, and if I apply will that affect my visa? If someone can help me to get more deatils whether i can apply or not? I am from India and applied for visit visa to London.. Visit visa was refused stating that I don't have a property and not much in bank account.

Comment: I have edited both the title and body of your question for clarity, without changing the facts or the questions you ask. If you disagree with my edits, you can roll back my edits to restore your original text.

Answer (score 0):

The Rules pertaining to a Visitor visa and a work visa are completely different. The former requires the applicant to prove they can support themselves during their visit and that they will leave at the end of the visit. The latter allows you to come to or stay in the UK to do an eligible job that pays at least the prescribed minimum salary.

Unlike a Visitor visa, typically the Rules pertaining to a work visa will set out the exact amount of funds an applicant must have. For example, when you apply for a Skilled Worker visa, you’ll need to have enough money to:

- pay the application fee - the standard fee ranges from £625 to £1,423 depending on your circumstances
- pay the healthcare surcharge - this is usually £624 per year
- support yourself when you arrive in the UK - you’ll usually need to have at least £1,270 available (unless you’re exempt)

You’ll pay a lower application fee if your job is on the shortage occupation list.

https://www.gov.uk/skilled-worker-visa

A previous Visitor visa refusal for lack of funds and/or ties to home is highly unlikely that to have much/any bearing if you meet all the eligibility criteria for the work visa you’re applying for.

Comment: Logically because the whole point of a work visa is that you make enough money in the UK so you can afford to stay, and that you work instead of returning home.